# Issue applying script to second sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have no idea how to code. I use to make website on HTML, so my knowledge is limited. I piece together and alter existing codes. I got decent on Excel VBA, but then needed to start using google sheets. So, that said...

I have a spreadsheet with two sheets, 'MIS' and 'Admin'. I have a bunch of code a formula that assigns a value (1,2,3...) based on how many of two drop-down criteria that each line matches (1 if it matches criteria #1, 2 if matches criteria #2, and 3 if it matches both). The code then hides everything and unhides only those with numbers matching the criteria. I need this to be clean and quick, it's for people who can barely use computers.

The problem is, the code only works on the first page. I tried using the same code, tried amending the code, and I tried inserting 'Admin' in about half a million places. Please help. The admin function is my latest attempt. This is where I inserted 'Admin' in a dozen places. Also, if you see anything I'm using that is slowing down the code, I could use some help with that too. There are 6 functions, which basically do the same thing using the same code but corresponding to different number combinations. The one in question is below.

```
function Admin(){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheets('Admin')[0];
    var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow());

    sheet.hideRows(8,sheet.getLastRow());

    var values = range.getValues();

    for (var i=0; i<values.length; i++){
        if(values[i][0] === 3){
            sheet.showRows(i+1);   
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: To clarify: "I have a bunch of code a formula that " which should read "I have a bunch of code that is based on a formula that places a value in column A that corresponds to"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is your 'only the first sheet' problem, you're sort of combining two methods of defining a sheet:

```
var sheet = ss.getSheets('Admin')[0];
```

You can get a specific sheet by name by using the .getSheetByName() method i.e.

```
var adm_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Admin');
var mis_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('MIS');
```

Or you can get a sheet by index

```
var adm_sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]; //returns first sheet
var mis_sheet = ss.getSheets()[1]; //returns second sheet
```

Lastly, you can get all of the sheets in your spreadsheet and list them in an array like this:

```
var sheets = ss.getSheets();
```

And then use the index of the sheet you need in this array like so:

```
sheets[0] //the first sheet
sheets[1] //the second sheet
```

Comment: Thanks, it actually turned out to be related to the fact that my var sheet reference was repeated and it was reading sheet from one of the other function codes. But what you said made me realize I need to give these things different names!